# How to get the sum of odd integers in loop in c++

Tags: c++

Guys i'm trying to output the sum of all the odd numbers between a and b. Despite the conditions given, there would always be numbers smaller than 'a' outputted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()

{
int a =0;
int b =0;
int c=0;
std:: cout <<"Enter a number: \n";
std::cin >> a;
std:: cout <<"Enter a number: \n";
std::cin >> b;

int sum=0;
for(c; c%2!=0, c >= a, c <=b ; c+=2)
{
    std::cout << "This is one of the odd numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " : "<< c << std::endl;
    sum +=c;
}
std::cout << "The sum is : " <<sum;
return 3;
}
```

Comment: Check you loop: it starts at `c=0` and stops when `c >= a`

Comment: @tobi303 *stops when `c > b`

Comment: The expression `c%2!=0, c >= a, c <=b` doesn't do what you expect it to do (I guess), read about [the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) to understand why. Do you mean `c%2!=0 && c >= a && c <=b`?

Comment: @LogicStuff ups yes, anyhow my confusion just proves that his loop is not as clear as it could be ;)

Comment: You still can not incorporate all @Joachim suggested into a loop condition. Checking `c % 2 != 0` doesn't go together with `c += 2`...

Comment: `x²` is the sum of first x odd numbers. (e.g.: `9 = 1+3+5`). We also know that there are `(y+1)/2` is the number of odd number up to `y` (e.g.: `y=5 => (y+1)/2=3 => {1,3,5}`. In your case this would resolve into `sumOdd(a) = ((a+1)/2)²`. You need the difference between these two: `abs(sumOdd(a) - sumOdd(b))` (e.g. `a=5, b=8` => `abs(9 - 16) = 7`. Please be aware that the sum doesn't include the lower bound if it is odd.

Comment: @SimonKraemer certainly an interesting approach, thank you.

Comment: @LogicStuff okay so I changed it into `for(c=a; c%2!=0 && c >= a&& c <=b ; c++)` but it still doesn't work ?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb27fbe4d591c5c5

Comment: @SimonKraemer umm it's blank...?

Comment: What is blank? The link works perfectly fine here with FF and IE. Do you have any script blocker activated?

Comment: @SimonKraemer i'm using google chrome. I tried Microsoft edge but it's still empty. Can you send me an ideone link or something ? Much appreciated

Comment: http://ideone.com/3N10xH

Comment: wow thanks! However i am still a beginner at this so there's still some parts i haven't fully understood yet. I am learning loop so any chance you can make do with what i originally posted? It would be great to have comparisons.

Answer (score -2):

Initialize the value of c with a 
Try this

for(c=a; c%2!=0 && c >= a && c <=b ; c++)
{
    std::cout << "This is one of the odd numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " : "<< c << std::endl;
    sum +=c;
}

Comment: If "a" is an even number, you don't loop at all.